# AVPlayer with custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have created an AVPlayer object in custom UITableViewCell. As video playing inside UITableViewCell. When I leave that UIViewController, AVPlayer still running in background. How to stop AVPlayer and remove AVPlayerLayer from custom UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!
```

Assign your UITableViewCell Player to this videoPlayer.

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      videoPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
   }
```

Comment: Thanks!
Now I am creating AVPlayer object on UIViewController and handling that object by delegate on UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the player on viewDidDisappear

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       self.playerViewController.player?.pause()
   }
```

Comment: Object inside UITableViewCell class. I have not reference in UIViewController.